# Sending files with REST API

Tags: rest-api, files

We are using the REST API to create and update records for a client (using PHP).
So far this has been fine but can't seem to send files and associate this with a record.

Have tried using the "document" and "contentVersion" endpoints to send the file as a multipart message (using both curl and guzzle) as per the documentation at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm#inserting_a_new_document

The endpoint posting to is `/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/ContentVersion`

However, no matter always end up getting an error response:

> "You have sent us an Illegal URL or an improperly formatted request"

With no further information or context on the specific error.

Anybody got any experience with PHP and the Salseforce Rest API to help?

Cole

Comment: welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. Are you able to share any specifics on what you're putting in the request and/or your exact code? Otherwise, we'll not be able to tell you what's improperly formatted.

Comment: Thank you @KrisGoncalves - I have posted up the sample (POST) submission here: https://gist.github.com/cole007/b997f3b205b5f09eef7fd8d7df62d917

Note this is the raw contents and header - not the PHP code used to submit these.

Comment: This 400 error is all about encoding the payload correctly. You mention trying this with curl or guzzle yet your gist does not show this. Please edit your question and provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, it's preferable to inline the repro into the question so that it's available here for posterity versus a (possibly) dead link.

Comment: Thank you - sample PHP code using Guzzle client here …

https://gist.github.com/cole007/8e2f08e2dcd58d55d0f757ae9e416df2

Comment: Have included in the gist an example of the payload am sending (have tried both with and without base64 encoding of the file contents)

Comment: FYI: you can [edit] your question with the gist or even include the [code](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) directly in your question

Comment: `$sf_instance` is undefined in your example

Comment: you probably figured it out by now but the name is supposed to be `entity_content`, not `entity_document`